# How to get the recipients of an email using EWS

Tags: c#, arrays, email, collections, exchangewebservices

I am struggling to get the recipients of an email.

I understand that the Recipients is an array, so I need to put them into an array, but my code will not compile:

```
do
{
// set the prioperties we need for the entire result set
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(
    BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
    ItemSchema.Subject,
    ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,
    ItemSchema.DisplayTo, EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients,
    EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead,
    EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments, ItemSchema.MimeContent,
    EmailMessageSchema.Body, EmailMessageSchema.Sender,
    ItemSchema.Body) { RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text };

// load the properties for the entire batch
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(results, view.PropertySet);

e2cSessionLog("\tcommon.GetUnReadMailAll", "retrieved " + results.Count() + " emails from Mailbox (" + common.strInboxURL + ")");

foreach (EmailMessage email in results)

// looping through all the emails
{

    emailSenderName = email.From.Address;
    sEmailSubject = email.Subject;
    emailDateTimeReceived = email.DateTimeReceived.ToShortDateString();
    emailHasAttachments = email.HasAttachments;
    ItemId itemId = email.Id;
    emailDisplayTo = email.DisplayTo;
    sEmailBody = email.Body; //.Text;
    Recipients = email.ToRecipients;
    ....
```

the last line there will not compile, as apparently I cannot implicitly convert the collection ToRecipients to a string...

so I tried to loop through all the ToRecipients:

```
string[] Recipients;
for (int iIdx=0; iIdx<-email.ToRecipients.Count; iIdx++)
{
    Recipients[iIdx] = email.ToRecipients[iIdx].ToString();
}
```

but I have obviously not declare this properly, as it won't compile with the message that `Recipients` is unassigned.

What is the correct way to assign this?

I need to be able to use the recipients again later - for example to send them a 'heads up' email about a problem for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the array correctly, and you need to use the Address property of a ToRecipient:

```
var Recipients = new string[email.ToRecipients.Count];
for (int iIdx = 0; iIdx < email.ToRecipients.Count; iIdx++) {
    Recipients[iIdx] = email.ToRecipients[iIdx].Address;
}
```

BTW, I think you have a typo in your pseudo-code:

```
for(...; iIdx<-email.ToRecipients.Count; ...) {
```

You have a minus `-` in there, which would result in no iterations since the first iteration would not pass (0 < -count is `false`). I think you mean

```
for(...; iIdx < email.ToRecipients.Count; ...) {
```

### UPDATE

A much simpler, less error-prone, solution would be:

```
var recipients = email.ToRecipients
    .Select(x => x.Address)
    .ToList(); // or ToArray()
```

Comment: +1 thanks, and thanks also for the typo (DOH), in the end I chose to use a List, but this would also solve the problem!